# How to check if two cells have the same row in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on a huge file that gets data from a spreadsheet. I need to match the store number and the store name and return the correct address. This would be easy but a lot of the store numbers repeat, so I can't just match the store number. I also have to match the store name. Sample data:

```
Store Name         Store Number     Address
Kroger - Dallas    333              358 Street
Kroger - Dallas    450              123 Street
Kroger - Delta     450              453 Street
Kroger - Atlanta   450              648 Street
Kroger - Atlanta   258              284 Street
HEB                450              349 Street
```

I already know how to return the address if the store number matches, but with these stores, their store numbers sometimes conflict with each other. When working with Sam's Clubs, it's easy since no store number conflicts with each other so all the data gets returned wonderfully.

I'm trying to first check if the name contains "Dallas" or "Atlanta", etc. and then check for the store number that related to that name, and return the address.

This is the formula I'm trying but it says there's an error. Where D3 is the cell that contains the store name and store number.

```
 =IF(SEARCH("Kroger", $D$3), IF(ROW(SEARCH("Dallas", D3))=ROW(MATCH(INT(RIGHT(D3, LEN(D3)-FIND("#", D3))), B2:B985)), "Match!", "No Match."), IF(RIGHT($D$3,1)="#","Enter a Valid Store Number", INDEX(Locations!$C$2:$C$985,MATCH(INT(RIGHT($D$3,LEN($D$3)-FIND("#",$D$3))),Locations!$B$2:$B$985,0),)))
```

If I replace the IF(ROW()=ROW()) with this:

```
IF(ROW(D3)=ROW(D3), "Match!", "No Match.")
```

It works so I know the error isn't in the rest of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Given the sample data you provided I'm assuming the store name and the store number are separate fields, and you are simply matching those same fields in a new spreadsheet to bring back just the address.

The formula provided indicates that it may not be formatted consistently or the same.

If the data is formatted the same in both spreadsheets an INDEX MATCH formula should work fine.

The below array formula will match the values in column E & F with the respective values in column A & B, and then returning the corresponding value in C.

It's an array formula so you will need to enter it using **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=INDEX(C:C|MATCH(E1&F1|A:A&B:B|0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Formula, where D is the column for Store Name and you can drag it down for each Name it will give you the matching Address
`=IFERROR(IF(AND(FIND("Kroger",D3,1)>0,FIND("Dallas",D3,1)>0),OFFSET(D3,0,2),""),"")`
But if you need to search all Store Name at a time with one Formula, you need a different one.
Another formula is by combining the store name and Store Number using MATCH and OFFSET, A:A and B:B is the array of your information  (Store Name and Store Number) with match you will get the row with offset you will get the address with A1 as start reference where the Header Store Name is.
`=OFFSET(A1,MATCH("Kroger - Dallas"&"450",A:A&B:B,0)-1,2)`
Use **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER** it is an array formula

Comment: I do need to search all stores names at once with a formula. The VLOOKUP works but a lot of stores have "Kroger - Dallas" with different store numbers. There are over 10 variations of "Kroger - ....." with almost 50 stores each that have different store numbers. So if the cell said "Kroger - Dallas #344" then I need to match the store name AND store number from a big set of data.

Comment: I have updated the formula to check the corresponding store number also